# Calling pyspark from the command line results in error ('pyspark' not recognized as internal/external command/operable program/batch file.)

Tags: apache-spark, command-line, pyspark

I am using Spark version 2.3.3 and trying to call `pyspark` from my command line which results in the following error:

> c:\spark>pyspark 'pyspark' is not recognized as an internal or
>   external command, operable program or batch file.

I have checked my environment variables to ensure `SPARK_HOME` is referenced in path etc (See attached images) Has anybody experienced this problem before? Any clues as to what the issue could be would be much appreciated.

[image: SPARK home]

Answer (score 0):

I guess you need to restart the Windows to apply the new PATH you've added.You also can add it instantly with `setx`:

```
setx path "%path%;%SPARK_HOME%\bin"
```

And then run `pyspark`

Comment: Thank you Soheil, I'll try that

Comment: let me know if it helped!

Comment: Unfortunately still getting the same problem. One thing I noticed, is when I change the directory from C:\spark to C:\spark\bin\ and try to call pyspark I get the following error
'python' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

Comment: Figured out the issue. It relates to permissions. DCOM Error 10016. Video fix here on Youtube https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vjz8uLblc_8